# Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 51.0 (java 7)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am getting an error that says "source code does not match bytecode" 
 with the description that "Decompiled .class file, bytecode version: 51.0 (java 7)" when I am calling `onClickSelect()` method.

It brings me to `AppCompatViewInflater` class and highlights its built-in `onClick()` method.

AppCompatViewInflater:

```
public void onClick(@NonNull View v) {
       if (this.mResolvedMethod == null) {
           this.resolveMethod(this.mHostView.getContext(), this.mMethodName);
       }

    try {
        this.mResolvedMethod.invoke(this.mResolvedContext, v);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException var3) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non-public method for android:onClick", var3);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException var4) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute method for android:onClick", var4);
        }
    }
```

My code:

```
public void onClickSelect(View view) {
        TextView attack_pts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min_attack_value);
        TextView defense_pts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min_defense_value);
        TextView health_pts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.min_health_value);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, PokemonListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("min attack pts", attack_pts.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("min defense pts", defense_pts.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("min health pts", health_pts.getText().toString());
        startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: It means exactly what it says. Recompile and retest.

Comment: You need to verify your build process. Make sure the project is properly built before running the app (use Build | Rebuild Project action).

Answer (score -1):

Can you check the .class file java version and version that you are currently using to decompile.

It should be same.

Comment: How do I check the java version of AppCompatViewInflater?